# Describe the curve in the complex plane determined by $z = e^{(-1-i)t}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe the curve in the complex plane determined by $z = e^{(-1-i)t}$ where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: From Terminator 2: "you forgot to say please..." ;)

Comment: Break it into two parts $e^{-t}$ and $e^{-it}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $z(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, with $x(t)=e^{-t}\cos t$ and $y(t)=-e^{-t}\sin t$; in other words, $x(t)=\operatorname{Re}z(t)$, and $y(t)=\operatorname{Im}z(t)$. I used the fact that

$$z(t)=e^{-t}e^{-it}=e^{-t}(\cos t-i\sin t).$$
For all $t\in [0,2\pi]$ one has

$$|z(t)|^2=x(t)^2+y(t)^2=e^{-2t};$$

this means that the point $z(t)$ lies on the circle centered at $0$ in $\mathbb C$ with radius $e^{-t}$. The biggest circle is the one at $t=0$, while the smallest is the one at $t=2\pi$. Now, try to find the points

$z(0), z(\frac{\pi}{2}), z(\pi), z(\frac{3\pi}{2}), z(2\pi)$

on the corresponding circles and "join the dots". This last passage is motivated by the fact that both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are continuous functions of $t$.